# How to stock list with Hive in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies, flutter-hive

I'm looking to stock some lists into Hive.

In my main.dart, I got:

```
Hive.registerAdapter(MedicalConstantsAdapter());
await Hive.openBox(MEDICAL_CONSTANTS);
```

In my medical.dart, I got:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class MedicalConstants extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  List<SystolicPressure> systolicPressure;
  @HiveField(1)
  List<DiastolicPressure> diastolicPressure;

  MedicalConstants({
    this.systolicPressure,
    this.diastolicPressure
  });

  MedicalConstants.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['systolic_pressure'] != null) {
      systolicPressure = new List<SystolicPressure>();
      json['systolic_pressure'].forEach((v) {
        systolicPressure.add(new SystolicPressure.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['diastolic_pressure'] != null) {
      diastolicPressure = new List<DiastolicPressure>();
      json['diastolic_pressure'].forEach((v) {
        diastolicPressure.add(new DiastolicPressure.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.systolicPressure != null) {
      data['systolic_pressure'] =
          this.systolicPressure.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.diastolicPressure != null) {
      data['diastolic_pressure'] =
          this.diastolicPressure.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class MedicalConstantsAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MedicalConstants> {
  @override
  final typeId = 1;

  @override
  MedicalConstants read(BinaryReader reader) {
    return MedicalConstants()
      ..diastolicPressure
      ..systolicPressure = reader.read();
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, MedicalConstants obj) {
    writer
      ..write(obj.systolicPressure)
      ..write(obj.diastolicPressure);
  }
}
```

And to finish, in my session.dart, I got:

```
Hive.box(MEDICAL_CONSTANTS).values.toList().forEach((element) {
  print(element);
});
```

The 2 list I'm getting are from my endpoint and datas stock in the list already.

I just for the moment display my result to the print.

I tried to use the command from hive `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`, but nothing happened, and that's why maybe my MedicalConstantsAdapter is not build properly?

Is there someone with an idea how to use it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

medical.dart

```dart
// add 'g' to file name to indicate generated
part 'medical.g.dart'

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class MedicalConstants extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  List<SystolicPressure> systolicPressure;
  @HiveField(1)
  List<DiastolicPressure> diastolicPressure;

  MedicalConstants({
    this.systolicPressure,
    this.diastolicPressure
  });
}
```

The type adapter will be then generated to `medical.g.dart` once you run

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Comment: When i do that, visual say : The part-of directive must be the only directive in a part.
Try removing the other directives, or moving them to the library for which this is a part.

(I updated my code by the way)

Comment: For some reason, when I unplug my phone from my computer (build was running), the file generated. Don't know if it's working, I will repost here in few minutes

Comment: Ok it's not totally working, but I accepted the answer, thank you ! :)

Comment: i accidentally wrote 'part of'. it should be 'part' only. that would fix the directive issue

Comment: Yes I actually saw that and removed it, everything works fine now